# Regex pattern for characters in byte "string" except for specific punctuation - Python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text file that had to be read in as binary to work. I am attempting to extract some data and put into a csv file.

An example of some of the text looks like:

> b' "Title;""Date"";""Abstract"";""Patent Number"";""id"""\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"The object of my invention is to lessen the rapidity or amount of this diminution \t which I do by the addition of a new step in the process of making the lamp \t as follows : After the lamphas been exhausted of air and hermetically sealed by the fusion of the exhaust-tube in the usual manner \t I connect the lamp"";""12234"";"";1.0"   '

I want to extract snippets between the ";" and tried the following:

```
contentRegex = re.compile(b'\s{4,}"([\w+\s]+);(\d{4})\.\d;""([\w+\s+]+)"(.+[^;])')
```

It seems to work fine except for the last part where it continues to grab text after the first ";" it sees. So the following regex pattern seems to be wrong:

```
(.+[^;])
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have to read it in as binary?

Comment: "I want to extract snippets between the ";"" -- sounds like you want to do a lot more than that given how complex your regex is.

Comment: Why aren't you just splitting on ";"?

Comment: I can't read the file unless it's in binary. Also, had some decoding issues as there are a number of different formats within the file. I believe I can't split on ";" because the data is in byte format and not str.

Answer (score 0):

If you exactly need to use regexp try something like this:
`;(.*?);`
or
`;([a-zA-Z"]*?);`

Comment: I'd like to capture any character or punctuation (other than semicolon ; or new line) so [a-zA-Z] doesn't quite work, but thank you!

Comment: So, you can modify it with 0-9 and smth more to fit your needs

Comment: I'd also like to include every single punctuation mark EXCEPT for the semicolon. It doesn't seem like what I'm doing is very efficient...

Comment: @AlisonLT you can do it in two steps. First, use `;(.*?);` regexp. Second, send the result to the `[^;]` and it will cut the semicolons.